# Tag synonym: hg -> mercurial

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

could we please have a synonym from [hg](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/hg) to [mercurial](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mercurial) like we have on SO? I'm too new here to create it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now complete.

(we like to have answers on these so they don't show up as no answers..)